# Selenium Remote Webdriver issue using jdk 1.6

Tags: selenium, firefox

I need to run selenium tests using only jdk 1.6.0_45. I have been using firefox 49.0 with selenium-standalone-sever 2.43.1.jar. but I keep getting the following error:

```
    Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: 
    }},"app-system-defaults":{"firefox@getpocket.com":
    {"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0.4","st":1474361173000},"webcompat@mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0","st":1474361173000},"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.2","st":1474361172000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"49.0","st":1474361172000}},"app-system-share":{"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com.xpi","e":false,"v":"3.2","st":1442597402000}}}
    1476448669049   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
    1476448669059   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
    1476448669060   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
    1476448669075   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
    1476448669082   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database /tmp/anonymous8478643584785783937webdriver-profile/extensions.json
    1476448669083   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
    1476448669084   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
    1476448669086   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
    1476448669086   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
    1476448669086   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
    1476448669089   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.2
    1476448669094   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1476448669095   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1476448669095   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1476448669095   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1476448669095   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1476448669096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1476448669104   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1476448669104   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1476448669105   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1476448669105   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1476448669107   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1476448669109   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1476448669375   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
    1476448669376   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
    1476448669378   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
    1476448669390   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1476448669390   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1476448669391   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    *** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
    1476448669531   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1476448669531   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1476448669532   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    JavaScript error: file:///tmp/anonymous8478643584785783937webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js, line 11464: TypeError: this.server_ is undefined
   JavaScript error: chrome://fxdriver/content/server.js, line 38: NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570015 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
```

I have also tried with the following jars but it's still not working:

- selenium server-standalone-2.48.0.jar
- selenium server-standalone-2.49.0.jar
- selenium server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
- selenium server-standalone-3.0.0-beta4.jar

  Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share you tried code as well with all these jars..??